# Flutter start playing video from url without fully downloading it

Tags: flutter, video

Is there a way in Flutter to play a video from URL while it is still buffering?
I am building something like reels (shorts), so I want the video to start right away without having to wait for loading it fully to avoid long loading time for videos, I want it to start playing while still buffering.

I am using [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package

Here is the code:

```
class VideoPlayerPreview extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  VideoPlayerPreviewState createState() => VideoPlayerPreviewState();
}

class VideoPlayerPreviewState extends State<VideoPlayerPreview> {
  VideoPlayerController? _controller;
  VideoPlayerController? _toBeDisposed;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _playVideo(url: widget.url!);
  }


  Future<void> _playVideo({XFile? file, String? url}) async {
    if (mounted) {
      controller = VideoPlayerController.network(url);
      _controller = controller;
      await controller.setVolume(1);
      await controller.initialize();
      await controller.setLooping(true);
      await controller.play();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_controller != null) {
      return AspectRatioVideo(
        _controller!,
      );
    } else {
      return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      ));
    }
  }
}

class AspectRatioVideo extends StatefulWidget {

  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  @override
  AspectRatioVideoState createState() => AspectRatioVideoState();
}

class AspectRatioVideoState extends State<AspectRatioVideo> {
  VideoPlayerController get controller => widget.controller;
  bool initialized = false;

  void _onVideoControllerUpdate() {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    if (initialized != controller.value.isInitialized) {
      initialized = controller.value.isInitialized;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(_onVideoControllerUpdate);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (initialized) {
      return Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(controller),
            ),
      );
    } else {
      return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your player supports hls streaming so to play directly from URL without buffering you need to encode your videos files in hls format.
for hls overview please check this
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming

try check this hls video url
https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8

Comment: Sounds great, but If I am uploading videos with image_picker, how to encode it to hls?

Comment: I don't think there is any way out for doing this on app side as hls is apple proprietor thing not open source, you need to use third party encoding services to encode your files and deploy theme on server.
you can use amazaon encoding services or others.
Amazon you need to send your original file for encoding from App, you can use their REST API.